# Backend Create user with signup JWT

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to create a restful web application with Springboot and Gradle. I use JWT for authentication. When a user logged the backend creates a user token for the user. this token he uses whenever he opens another page to retrieve his data.

What I'm trying to do is making a signup page, but the problem is that I cant send information to my backend without a Bearer token. How do I send a post method to create a user without authentication on this one single POST operation?

To generate a token for a user that exists

```java
@PostMapping(value = "${jwt.get.token.uri}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtTokenRequest authenticationRequest)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());

        UserDetails userDetails = jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtTokenResponse(token));
    }
```

What I want to call to create a user in my database:
(want to do this POST without authorization)

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user){

        HBMUserService HBMuserService = new HBMUserService();
        User createdUser = HBMuserService.saveUser(user);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(createdUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

My application properties:

```java
jwt.signing.key.secret=SecretKey
jwt.get.token.uri=/authenticate
jwt.refresh.token.uri=/refresh
jwt.http.request.header=Authorization
jwt.token.expiration.in.seconds=604800
```

Comment: Are you facing any error ?

Comment: i think you need to exclude signup endpoint from your spring security config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found out where my JWT Ignores my Auth path for login and added my signup path there as well.

```
.antMatchers(
    HttpMethod.POST,
    authenticationPath,
    "/signup"
)
```